# How to get a Docker image object in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this code in a Jenkins pipeline, and it runs

```
def myImage = docker.build(...)
myImage.withRun(...) {img ->
    println img.id
}
```

IOW `docker.build()` returns some Jenkins pipeline Docker object that knows about the `withRun()` function.

But with this code I have to build the Docker image every time.

What if I want to pull the Docker image from a registry? How can I get the equivalent Jenkins pipeline Docker object that will have the `withRun()` function too? IOW, how can I make this (pseudo)code work? I say "pseudo" since there's no `docker.pull()` that I'm aware of?

```
docker.withRegistry(...)
  def myImage = docker.pull('someImage:latest')
  myImage.withRun() (...) {img ->
    println img.id
  }
}
```

Comment: [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation covers the various permutations here.  `docker.image('...').withRun('...') { ... }` will do it.

Comment: @DavidMaze i read that, missed the point that I can do `docker.image("myImage:version")`. Put this as an answer if you wish, and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation covers the typical cases.  This is described under [Running "sidecar" containers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers): you can call `docker.image('someImage:latest')` to get the image object, and its `withRun` method will pull the image if needed.

```groovy
docker.withRegistry(...) {
  docker.image('someImage:latest').withRun() { container ->
    println container.id
  }
}
```

The Jenkins server itself has documentation on the globals; I can't easily find a canonical online reference, but try navigating to `/pipeline-syntax/globals` on your local Jenkins server and looking for the `docker` object.  You can manually `image.pull()` if you need to (though note that `.withRun()` will pull the image on its own if it doesn't already exist locally).

Your examples all try to print out the ID of the image.  That doesn't seem to be a property of the `image` object; `image.id` can exist but may not be informative

```groovy
def image = docker.image('someImage:latest')
image.pull()
echo image.id // will print "someImage:latest"
```

If you really need to know this, you can run `docker inspect` to find it.

```groovy
sh "docker inspect -f '{{ .Id }}' ${image.id}"
```